# Is there a phrase that sounds like "perform our cell"?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/BfS2H1y6tzQ?t=180)

> Before solving the puzzle, let's write a
>   second version of this function that is
>   more compact. We will call this function
>   random walk 2. We will perform our cell
>   and programmers duty and write a
>   docstring.

I am confused about the last sentence. Writing a docstring is one of the duties of programmers; this is easy to understand. What does "perform our cell" mean? I searched this phrase on many online dictionaries and got no results.

Could someone give a clue?

Comment: Haven’t listened to it, but my guess is that they’re saying “solemn programmer's duty”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jim says in the comments, "perform our solemn programmer's duty and write a docstring."

One's [solemn duty](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/solemn) is doing one's duty:

> Made with deep sincerity or invoking the force of a religion.

In this case it's a hyperbole, saying that it's the deeply sincere duty of programmers to write a docstring.